# Pimcore 3.1.1 ALTER TABLE BUG

Tags: alter-table, pimcore

I installed Pimcore 3.1.1 and I have lot of issue with message like:

```
(
    [message] => SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'p_index_person__id'; check that column/key exists, query was: ALTER TABLE `object_store_3` DROP INDEX `p_index_person__id`;
    [method] => query
    [arguments] => Array
        (
            [0] => ALTER TABLE `object_store_3` DROP INDEX `p_index_person__id`;
        )

)

(
    [message] => SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'p_index_person__type'; check that column/key exists, query was: ALTER TABLE `object_store_3` DROP INDEX `p_index_person__type`;
    [method] => query
    [arguments] => Array
        (
            [0] => ALTER TABLE `object_store_3` DROP INDEX `p_index_person__type`;
        )

)

(
    [message] => SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'p_index_Options'; check that column/key exists, query was: ALTER TABLE `object_store_12` DROP INDEX `p_index_Options`;
    [method] => query
    [arguments] => Array
        (
            [0] => ALTER TABLE `object_store_12` DROP INDEX `p_index_Options`;
        )

)
```

Same errors are reported [in Pimcore forum](https://www.pimcore.org/board/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1726&p=6580&hilit=alter%20table#p6580) at the bottom of the post.

Is there an issue about this ? Currently, I can't work with Pimcore. Every change in object structure corrupts the data.
Any advice ?

**UPDATE #001 :**
I have tried Johan's solutions :

**First one**

1. Backup your entire system
2. Export class defintions from within admin
3. Import class definitions from within admin, save class

**Second**

1. Export the class definitios from within admin
2. Remove files in website/var/classes
3. Import your class definitions again

I always have the same errors in log with alter table.

When I try to add an ObjectBricks to my object, I see this :
[image: No choice in ObjectBricks]

Thanks for your help.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to

1. Backup your entire system
2. Export class defintions from within admin
3. Import class definitions from within admin, save class

If that does not do the trick then you could try to (be sure you did a backup Before and know your recover steps)

1. Export the class definitios from within admin
2. Remove files in website/var/classes
3. Import your class definitions again

/Johan

Comment: ok, I will try. I'll come back for give the results of the manipulation

Comment: First try :
`Server threw exception - could not perform action. Please reload the admin interface and try again.
URL: /admin/class/bulk-commit
Params:
-> data: {"checked":true,"type":"class","name":"catalog","displayName":"catalog"}
-> filename: C:\xampp5612\htdocs\idda/website/var/tmp/bulk-import.tmp
Method: post
Message: 

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not add child NULL' in C:\xampp5612\htdocs`

I try the second way  with remove files in wembsite/var/classes...

Comment: thanks for your help @Johan but it not resolve my problem.
Any other proposition  ?

Comment: what if you export your class definitions using the bulk export and try to import them in a clean new install (ie restart from fresh with a clean webroot and unzip). Does it work then?